# How to cnnect service android? Included new LocalBinder lib

Tags: android, android-service, android-service-binding

How is the best easiest way to startService and bind service to work in my activity?

I got to implement a LocalBinder service class into my activity class is my purpose, but how to use the startService and GetSerivce correctly?

IS it a good way to use 
`Intent i = new Intent(this, myclass.class);` then start service `startService(i);` and GetService into my local myclassvariable by a binder but how in that case? Do i need a Binder to be implemented here?
What i want isto then read from broadcastreceiver in this activity class?

Comment: If you use broadcasts, then you don't need to bind yourself to the activity I guess

Comment: Well what i understand i do need to bind to fetch data into broadcastReceiver?

Comment: No broadcasts work without binding

Comment: Ah ok, then do you know how i can use this mycalss service and get data into broadcastReceiver?

Comment: So i only need to startService from my onCreat activity then how to use methods from the service class?

Comment: Just start the service and postBroadcast in the service when it needs to, and implement onReceive where you want to handle the broadcast

Comment: Solved by registerBroadcast and bindService!